# Exclude subfolder in Codeigniter using htaccess rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, mod-authz-host

I'm using following `.htaccess` code to hide `index.php` in `CodeIgniter`.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I've defined a password protected subdirectory `[admin]` under webroot with index.php as:
**HTACCESS**

```
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "C:\xampp\htdocs\personal\admin\passwd"
require valid-user
```

But while I try to access admin folder, it is throwing `404 ERROR`. Actually, the .htaccess on webroot is overwriting the htaccess in sub-directory.

The .htaccess under sub-directory is working if following line is removed in webroot

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Try with `RewriteCond $1 !^(admin)` before last line in root htaccess.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(phpmyadmin/.*)$`

`ErrorDocument 401 default`

`RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]`

This line worked for me